# How to display DrawerLayout above HeaderLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

my mainActivity is containing DrawerLayout to display sliding menu + ViewPager for tabs navigation. I've hided the actionbar and i replace it with a big linearLayout to implement the actionbar/tabs alternatif and also a layout containing button between them.
My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="@color/light_gray_2"> 

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >
  <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:background="@color/blue_buzzvibe"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         Here title and menu button (ActionBar alternatif)

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/options_buttons_campaign"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

     Here 4 layout for buttons

  </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs_layout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

        Here 2 layout for tabs

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_main_msg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
   <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
   <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"   
    android:background="@color/menu_list_background"

    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this xml lyaout my drawer is display bellow the big layout. and i want to display drawer in all the screen height.
Here a screenShot of what i have https://i.stack.imgur.com/icMfv.png
and here a screenshot of what i want https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKwmp.png

Comment: I've already hided it. i want to have possibility to swipe left from everywhere to open menuDarwer and i want to keep the header layout shown below the menu. like the 2sd screenshots

Comment: i've tried to add the header layout inside the DrawerLayout. but the header Layout is not shown.